# How to (numerically) model a phosphoric acid titration curve

Tags: titration, buffer, numerical-analysis

I've been learning how to simulate a 1M phosphoric acid titration curve using numerical methods in R.

So far has this has been the best curve:

[image]

Notice how it flattens out (artificially) towards the left.

I am not certain if this is a programming and / or a "chemistry" issue.

---

The system is defined by charge balance, mass balance, and equilibrium equations:

$$[\ce{H3A}] + [\ce{H2A-}] + [\ce{HA^{2-}}] + [\ce{A^{3-}}] = P_{CA}$$

$$[\ce{H+}] + [\ce{Na+}] = [\ce{H2A-}] + 2[\ce{HA^{2-}}] + 3[\ce{A^{3-}}] + Kw/[\ce{H+}]$$

$$K_{a, 1} = [\ce{H2A-}] [\ce{H+}] / [\ce{H3A}]$$

$$K_{a, 2} = [\ce{HA^{2-}}] [\ce{H+}] / [\ce{H2A^-}]$$

$$K_{a, 3} = [\ce{A^{3-}}] [\ce{H+}] / [\ce{HA^{2-}}]$$

I've posted a very similar question [at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880202/r-nleqslv-difficulties-solving-for-ph-in-an-acid-base-buffer) and shared code for the simulation over there, using R's `nleqslv::nleqslv` (go have a look if you'd like to).

I thought this is also a good place for this issue. For instance, [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/43422) (and the ones it links to) do seem to be useful, but I'm not sure how to solve that equation for $[\ce{H3O+}]$ (called $x$ over there).

I would like to know which is the best way to simulate a titration curve.

And also: are the equations I used correct? do you know what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You may compare the visual result with other's solutions in the field, e.g. [CurTipot](http://www.iq.usp.br/gutz/Curtipot_.html), _especially_ to avoid the sharp transition above $[\ce{Na+}] > 2$.  And, for future reference, learn how to use mhchem in the body of a question / answer / comment on ChemSE (_not_ in the title), e.g. [here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).

Comment: The exact answer, including the exact equation and titration curve, are already here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/43422/79678. I just found them. Also, the equation at the link is the same, except for trivial notation differences, as the one I have used for many years and use in an Excel spreadsheet here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/136203/79678. See the second spreadsheet.

Comment: So the answer I linked is one you already linked in your question! Argh! So I will do penance by telling you how to deal with that equation. You solve the equation just like in my spreadsheet (linked above). You can generate the titration curve two different ways. Easy way: pick a series of pH values in your desired range. Evaluate the equation for volume of added NaOH for each pH used. Then simply plot pH versus base volume added. This is the standard trick. Hard way: do algebra on the equation to yield a 5th order polynomial in hydrogen ion concentration. Solve that, using a root finder.

Comment: The hard way is how I make titration curves, since I use software with a nice root finder. Of course, you can use the equation with the solver in the Excel spreadsheet, but this is tedious because you would compute the pH for each base volume.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much easier is to calculate the inverse function $[\ce{Na+}]=f([\ce{H+}],K_\mathrm{a1},K_\mathrm{a2},K_\mathrm{a3})$.

Calculate fractions of respective phosphate forms as the function of $\ce{[H+]}$ and acidity constants.

First, calculate the common denominator $CD$:

$$a_1 = [\ce{H+}]^3$$
$$a_2 = [\ce{H+}]^2 \cdot K_\mathrm{a1} = a_1 \cdot \frac {K_\mathrm{a1}}{[\ce{H+}]}$$
$$a_3 = [\ce{H+}] \cdot K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot K_\mathrm{a2} = a_2 \cdot \frac {K_\mathrm{a2}}{[\ce{H+}]}$$
$$a_4 =  K_\mathrm{a1} \cdot K_\mathrm{a2} \cdot K_\mathrm{a3} = a_3 \cdot \frac {K_\mathrm{a3}}{[\ce{H+}]}$$

$$CD = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4$$

.. and then reuse it and its additive terms(*):

$$[\ce{H3A}]=c_0 \cdot \frac {a_1}{CD}$$

$$[\ce{H2A-}]=c_0 \cdot \frac {a_2}{CD}$$

$$[\ce{HA^2-}]=c_0 \cdot \frac {a_3}{CD}$$

$$[\ce{A^3-}]=c_0 \cdot \frac {a_4}{CD}$$

$c_0$ is the total phosphate concentration. From the fractions, you can get $\ce{[Na+]}$:

$$\ce{[Na+]} = \ce{[H2A-]} + 2 \cdot \ce{[HA^2-]} + 3 \cdot \ce{[A^3-]} + \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{[\ce{H+}]} - \ce{[H+]}$$

---

There is one important thing to consider: Titration dilutes the acid.

If  there is the volume $V_0$ of $\ce{H3PO4}$ with molar concentration $c_\mathrm{0,init}$, and if we spend the volume $V_1$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ solution of concentration $c_1$, then:

$$[\ce{Na+}]=c_1 \cdot \frac {V_1}{V_0 + V_1 }$$
$$c_0=c_\mathrm{0,init} \cdot \frac {V_0}{V_0 + V_1}$$

So perhaps the best approach can be:

- There are given concentrations of respective solutions
- For given volumes of respective solutions calculate $c_0$ and $\ce{[Na+]}$
- For given $c_0$ and $\ce{[Na+]}$, calculate $\ce{[H+]}$ by finding the solution of the equation below ( $f([\ce{H+}]) =  0$ ) by numerical methods, like [Regular falsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi), or Newton one.

$$ \ce{[H2A-]} + 2 \cdot \ce{[HA^2-]} + 3 \cdot \ce{[A^3-]} + \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{[\ce{H+}]} - \ce{[H+]} - \ce{[Na+]} = 0$$

For $y_1=f(x_1)$, $y_2=f(x_2)$, $y_1 \cdot y_2 \lt 0$, there is the Regula falsi iteration:

$$x_3 =  \frac{x_2 \cdot y_1 - x_1 \cdot y_2  }{  y_1 - y_2}$$

---

(*) Note that the formulas are quite common, I have just rearrange them. They should be able to be found on internet. I have once derived them myself, but not this time, because I remember them.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks :) I'll post the code in another answer and accept yours.

Comment: Hi again! I've been through this again and thought I'd try getting an analytical solution too. Do you think [this equation](https://bit.ly/3oCLz5O) is right?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The R code equivalent of Poutnik's answer, for refrence:

```
# Sumamente facil

Ka.1 <- 7.1 * 10^-3
Ka.2 <- 6.3 * 10^-8
Ka.3 <- 4.5 * 10^-13
Kw <- 10^-14

P_ca <- 1

pH.seq <- seq(from=0,to=14,length.out = 1000)

a1 <- function(H) H^3
a2 <- function(H) H^2 * Ka.1
a3 <- function(H) H * Ka.1 * Ka.2
a4 <- function(H) Ka.1 * Ka.2 * Ka.3
cd <- function(H) a1(H) + a2(H) + a3(H) + a4(H)

H3A <- function(H) P_ca * a1(H) / cd(H)
H2A <- function(H) P_ca * a2(H) / cd(H)
HA <- function(H) P_ca * a3(H) / cd(H)
A <- function(H) P_ca * a4(H) / cd(H)

OH <- function(H) Kw/H

Na <- function(H) H2A(H) + 2*HA(H) + 3*A(H) + OH(H) - H

Na.seq <- Na(H = 10^-pH.seq)

plot(Na.seq, pH.seq)
```

Also as suggested by Poutnik, a volume correction method was implemented [here](https://github.com/naikymen/titration/blob/d2bc176a4fb613d00b34469c04b405675011e2f8/R/phosphoric_titration_analytic.vol_correct.R#L30) (it's not Newton nor *regula falsi*, I got lazy).

## Plots

Get your plots here!

- https://github.com/naikymen/titration#3-experimental-data

Comment: Note that [H+] giving [Na+]=0 means [H+] of H3PO4 solution at c0. Negative [Na+] have no chemical meaning, it is just mathematical extrapolation. There will be need of iteration as c0=f([Na+]). You dilute the solution by titration.

Comment: See the A update, addressing dilution.

Comment: R code syntax note: They could not use boring  =, that had to use <- . I would hate to type it 1000 times.

Comment: Sorry about the arrows "<-" indeed assignment is not the same as equality :P (`Alt + -` is handy). I wrote an approximation method for the correction, calculating [Na] as before, but using it as an estimate for updating solution volume, then repeat until convergence. Seems to not-crash, but I'm not sure it converges where it's supposed to.